# where is stardict-repair option?

Tags: package-management

I have a dictionary in StarDict format without an *.ifo file.

I know how the file should look like, but I don't know how many words exactly the dictionary has, neither how to check it without counting manually [sic].

I've spent a couple of hours looking for the answer but found none.

I have installed stardict-tools from the Software Center, but apparently it isn't equipped with the option "stardict-repair", mentioned here: http://code.google.com/p/stardict-3/wiki/RepairStarDictDicts, on the StarDict project's page.

So my question is twofold: 1. how to obtain stardict-repair on Ubuntu 12.10 and get it running; 2. (perhaps a bit off-topic) how to conveniently create a correct ifo file if there isn't any.

Comment: note: this refers to stardict-index as well, and quite possibly to any other command other than stardict-editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tools are installed to `/usr/lib/stardict-tools/`. `stardict-index` and `stardict-verify` are both there. Since they are located outside of your current PATH setting, the terminal cannot find them to run.

To run them from the terminal, you have several options:

1. Open a terminal and use the fully qualified name that includes the path:

   `/usr/lib/stardict-tools/stardict-verify`
2. Browse to the stardict-tools directory and use the `./` prefix:

   `cd /usr/lib/stardict-tools`, then use `./startdict-verify`
3. If you find you use the tools a lot, you can add the directory to the PATH or add aliases, .desktop files, or make your own wrapper scripts, etc. But those things are probably not worth the trouble right now.

`stardict-repair`, however, is not included in the directory. The Ubuntu package is not the current version, so that could be the reason, or there could be another reason.

For making your own dictionaries, see[StarDict Create Dictionary](http://www.stardict.org/HowToCreateDictionary)

For details on the .ifo format, see [StarDict Formats](http://code.google.com/p/babiloo/wiki/StarDict_format)

If you must have the repair tool, you would need to compile and install the package from from source.

**How to Compile the Package**

**Download the source code**

Open a terminal in `~/Downloads`. The download will go to the directory you are in when you run the download command.

Run `hg clone https://code.google.com/p/stardict-3/` to download the source code.

**Pre-compilation steps**

There's a bug in 2 of the files that needs to be fixed. Because of changes to one of the required libraries, each file has a line that needs to be changed before they will compile.

The 2 files are `libcommon.h` and `libcommon.cpp`, but you can download the updated files.

The downloads are at http://code.google.com/p/stardict-3/issues/detail?id=31. Scroll down until you see the post with the replacement files attached.

Download each file into `~/Downloads/stardict-3/lib/src`, saying yes when asked if you want to replace the existing file.

A standard Ubuntu install will not automatically have tools for compiling installed, plus each app will its own required libraries.

For stardict tools, you need:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential automake libtool libmysqlclient-dev libpcre3-dev`

**Compiling**

```
cd ~/Downloads/stardict-3/
```

Most packages have a ready-made `configure` file that you would run at this point. With this package, you need to run a utility to create the `configure` file.

Make sure you are in the `stardict-3` directory (there are multiple autogen files in the structure and you need to run the right one), then:

```
./autogen.sh
```

Now run the configure file with the `--disable-dict` option to compile just the tools.

```
./configure --disable-dict
```

Compile the package with `make` (Note there's no `./` this time)

`make` is usually followed with `make install`, but I don't think we want to do that here, since it will copy over the files installed from the Ubuntu repository. Instead, `cd tools/src` where you will find the binaries you just compiled.

In the terminal, binaries will be the green files and will not have an extension. (Files with the same name ending in `.o` are intermediate files that are no longer needed, files ending in `.cpp` are the original source code and can also be ignored.

Copy `stardict-repair` and any other file that may not have been included before to `/usr/lib/stardict-tools`. You only need to copy the binary file. Remember the `./` when run you them.

One note: we compiled the newest version. It's possible, though I think really not very likely, that there may be some incompatibility between this version of stardict-repair and the rest of package you have. If so, it should be possible to compile a previous version of the tool.

Comment: Ok, great, I got it running - thank you! Only I noticed that the dictionary I have is probably in ColorDict, not StarDict format, as it contains a mysterious *.cdi file, which I thought was irrelevant... Can it be the reason why stardict-index returns "unsupported index type" message?

As for stardict-repair, I don't need it for now, but if I do, can I reach you for help?

Comment: Turns out I might actually need stardict-repair. Hope you're still willing to give me a hand :)

Comment: Sure. In fact, I just finished compiling it not two minutes ago. I'll edit my answer to include instructions (but it may take longer than a few minutes for me to post them). The process boils down to downloading the source code and issuing some terminal commands. It's easy.

Comment: There you go. I compiled everything once, then did it again as I wrote down each step to make sure everything worked and nothing was left out. If you have any problems, let me know. ColorDict and StarDict are supposed to be compatible as far as I know. You can also get GoldenDict, which I've played with a little and seems nice. I think anything about running converters and repairing files should probably go into new questions.

Comment: Thank you, I have only just followed your instructions, but there has been an error somewhere in the process.

Comment: I have downloaded the source (only I had to retry twice and only when I left Firefox the process was successful);
I have replaced the files from Stardict's page;
I have installed the required tools, only they were already installed, as I'd tried compiling StarDict before. I only managed to install dependencies though.
I went to stardict-3 dir, executed ./autogen.sh but got the message:
No 'gtk+-2.0', 'glib-2.0', 'libxml-2.0' found
I'll try to install them and report back.

Comment: Here's what I get when trying to install glib-2.0: "dpkg status database is locked by another process"; and: "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)"; when trying to install "libxml-2.0": "E: Unable to locate package libxml-2.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libxml-2.0'"; all installations performed with the command "sudo apt-get install".

Comment: After all that, the error message after running "./autogen.sh" states (in full): "No package 'libxml-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables STARDICT_CFLAGS
and STARDICT_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
configure: error: ./configure failed for lib"

Comment: gtk2 is `libgtk2.0-0` You may also need `libgtk2.0-dev`. glib2 is `glib2.0-0` and you may need `libglib2.0-dev`. libxml-2.0 is, unlike the others just `libxml2`. You may also need `libxml++2.6-2` and `libxml++2.6-dev` The error about locking came from having synaptic or the software center open at the same time as running apt-get. You may find it easier to do it from synaptic. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Got it. Everything went well, thank you for your help. Only one question left, can I move the directory to a more convenient location? And is it just the 'tools' I need to move, or some other folder? Thanks again!

Comment: The compiled binaries are in the /tools/src. You move just the binaries by themselves into a new folder anywhere you want.